# how to capture all requests and response on the page and perform action accordin to need on every response status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is their any way to monitor all the request made on the page triggered by script, click or anything else, it should not dependant on any script block or code just monitor what ever the request made, using jquery and javascript

example:

// monitor all the request made on the page.

```
monitor{

    success:function(){

    }
    error:function(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not track ***all the requests*** made on the webpage. However, you can track the requests that were made ***using jQuery*** by replacing $.ajax bay a wrapper.

Sample replacement plugin:

```
(function($, undefined) {
    // a private variable which will store the current active monitors
    var monitors = [];

    // a public API to add a monitor.
    $.monitorAjax = function(monitor) {
        monitors.push(monitor);
    };


    // here starts the implementation.

    // a function to wrap a callback (error or success) to make monitors functions called.
    var wrapCallback = function(name, settings) {
        return function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < monitors.length; i++) {
                var monitor = monitors[i];
                if(monitor[name] != null) monitor[name].apply(this, arguments);
            }
            if(settings[name] != null) settings[name].apply(this, arguments);
        };
    };


    // replace $.ajax by a wraped version which will replace success and error callbacks by wrappers.
    // note that you may also track calls and their settings if you want.
    var unwrappedAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function(url, settings) {
        if(settings == null) settings = {};

        var wrappedSuccess = wrapCallback("success", settings);
        var wrappedError = wrapCallback("error", settings);

        var wrappedSettings = $.extend({}, settings, {success: wrappedSuccess, error: wrappedError});

        return unwrappedAjax(url, wrappedSettings);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery maybe this:

```
var original_jquery_ajax=$.ajax;
$.ajax=function(){
    var a_fn, a_url;
    var cb=function(data, status, settings){
        a_fn(data, status, settings);
        console.log(a_url, data); // <-- here
    }
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        if(arguments[i] instanceof Object){
            if(arguments[i].success){
                a_fn=arguments[i].success; arguments[i].success=cb;
            }
            if(arguments[i].url) a_url=arguments[i].url;
        }
    if(typeof(arguments[0])=="string") a_url=argements[0];
    var aj=original_jquery_ajax.apply(null,arguments);
    var done_original=aj.done;
    aj.done=function(cb_fn){
        a_fn=cb_fn;
        done_original(cb);
        return aj;
    };
    return aj;
};
```

Now, when use $.ajax(url), you have in console the url and the returned data

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please add an explanation of what this is intended to do.  It is not clear from the block of code above that this even addresses the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can track all XML request and response like this. In this code, all the next XMLhttpRequest done on your webpage will write the response on the console.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(value) {
this.addEventListener("load", function(value){
    console.log(value.srcElement.response);//do what you want with the response
    }
}, false);
this.realSend(value);
};
```